# Azure ADAL OutlookServiceClient cannnot get data for non-admin account

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, adal, office365api

I am using Azure AD and Office 365 APIs to do the OAuth in my project. My problem is I can only have **admin** account (like "user@project.onmicrosoft.com") authorized and get data, but **non-admin regular** account (e.g., "user@hotmail.com") cannot.

How I implement the OAuth2

1. Get the Authorization code:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={my client Id}&redirect_uri={redirect uri}&resource=https%3A%2F%2Foutlook.office365.com%2F&state={guid}

2. Get access token and refresh token:

```or-tag-here
  TokenCache tokenCache = new TokenCache();
  ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
  AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authorityUrl, tokenCache);
  AuthenticationResult authResult = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(authorizationCode, new Uri(redirectUri), credential, recourceUri);
  string accessToken = authResult.AccessToken;
  string refreshToken = authResult.RefreshToken;
```

3. Get user's data (e.g., calendar events):

```or-tag-here
  OutlookServicesClient outlookClient = new OutlookServicesClient(new Uri(recourceUri + "/api/v2.0"), async () => { return accessToken; });
  List<Event> microsoftEvents = new List<Event>();
  var events = await outlookClient.Me.Events.Take(10).ExecuteAsync();
  foreach (IEvent calendarEvent in events.CurrentPage)
  {
    Event microsoftEvent = new Event
    {
      Subject = calendarEvent.Subject,
      Body = calendarEvent.Body,
      Location = calendarEvent.Location,
      Start = calendarEvent.Start,
      End = calendarEvent.End
    };
    microsoftEvents.Add(microsoftEvent);
  }
```

Note:

1. I am not sure if it is caused by Azure AD permission setting, so all available permissions are granted for "Windows Azure Active Directory" and "Office 365 Exchange Online" for now.
2. I did not pay for this Azure AD. I have an Office 365 Developer Account, and there is a link to AAD inside of Office Admin Centers. Not sure if this is the reason. Do I need to pay for an additional AAD subscription?

---

**Update on 11/2/2016**

1. Previous misunderstanding about accounts. Accounts like "user@project.onmicrosoft.com" are Office 365 accounts, not admin accounts. Hotmail accounts are actually regular microsoft accounts.
2. Mentioned by Jason, that Azure v1 endpoints do not support for microsoft accounts authorization. This is mainly pointing to the Authorization code generation.
3. The Azure AD application must be created in the new portal (https://apps.dev.microsoft.com). Otherwise, it would report Application not supported issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you granted ALL permissions for Exchange and Active Directory. Some of those permissions require an administrator, which is likely you're problem. You should only grant the permissions that your application requires.

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for getting back to me.
I removed some permissions, now "Windows Azure Active Directory" has Application permission "Read directory data" and delegated permission "Access the directory as the signed-in user". "Office 365 Exchange Online" has Application permission "Read and write calendars in all mailboxes" and delegated permissions to calendars. 
My purpose is to get user's events. now it reports error - "User is of type 'guest' in the organization but access is attempted as a regular user of this organization.";error_category="invalid_user".

Comment: How are you signing in?

Comment: I paste the auth code request link to browser and sign in as a non-admin user (might be a guest) and get the auth code. Then paste the auth code to my c# project to request tokens and data.

Comment: You can't use guest accounts, you need to login with an account that has a mailbox.

Comment: Hi Jason, sorry for the trivial questions! I am not sure how to specify it is a guest, can I see that in my above steps? If I am using a real hotmail address with mailbox, it is also 401 unauthorized.

Comment: You are using the Azure v1 OAuth endpoints, which only support Office 365 accounts (not Hotmail accounts, better known as Microsoft Accounts). If you want to support those, you need to use v2 endpoints. See https://dev.outlook.com/restapi/tutorial/dotnet for full walkthrough.

Comment: Good to know, thanks. I would try to implement on that.

Comment: Hi Jason,  I am probably using v2.0 endpoints, please have a look at the original post. Eg, https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant_Id/oauth2/token. If it is not, then where to find the v2 endpoints?

Comment: They have v2 in the URL :). Follow that link I sent, it will point you in the right direction.

Comment: Yeah, got it, appreciate so much. I would post update after figure it out.